# IntelliJ IDEA code completion not work in Node app as Java

Tags: java, node.js, intellij-idea

I just started to learning Node.js and I prefer to use the same IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) that I use for a long time. However, some code completion features does not seem to work.

For example:

In java, when I write something like `System.out.println(getName())` and press semicolon when the cursor (|) is on `System.out.println(getName()|)` it add semicolon at the end of the statement.

However, when I write something in a node project on `app.js` file `console.log(files)` and press press semicolon when the cursor (|) is on `console.log(files|), it adds semicolon to the  current cursor position instead of at the end of the statement.

So, how can I make IntelliJ to behave as it is on a Java file?

I tried some settings as on the screenshot, but does not make any sende :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzloi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please vote for [WEB-54481](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54481) to be notified on any progress with it